# How to use genymotion with no internet connection?

Tags: android, virtualbox, emulation, offline

I have genymotion 2.8.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 and I want to use it.
However, it says "User not authenticated" and wants me to sign-in but I want to use it offline, with no internet connection.
Obviously, it says "Network error" if I try to sign in.
Is there any way to use genymotion without authenticating?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to sign in the first time, just after installation - you'll also need connection to download the image. After that, it will work without an active internet connection.

So, in other words, set it up with an working internet connection, and then you will be able to work even offline. Just tried this approach here, and works well.

Comment: I know, but I want to set it up in a computer that is completely disconnected from the internet, and I will transfer the image through disk on key..

Comment: Well, I don't know how it is installed on Linux, but looking at the Windows installation it keeps the database and configurations at %user%\AppData\Local\Genymobile.. maybe discovering where it keeps such files in the linux version and copying them as well might help. It's a shot in the dark.